# Declaração de Controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope

Seguindo o script abaixo gerou um dúvida em qual declaração utilizar, na documentação do AngularJS encontrei as duas formas em exemplos diferentes, mas não encontrei uma explicação de qual declaração é usada ou se existe algum caso especifico para utilizar.

**aplicacao.js**:

```
//Declaração da aplicacao
$myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//Declaração dos controllers
var controller1 = function ($scope,$http){
 $scope.name = 'controller declaracao 1';
}

$myApp.controller('controller2',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.name = 'controller declaracao 2';
}]);
```

**index.html**:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
  <div ng-controller="controller1">{{name}}</div>
  <div ng-controller="controller2" >{{name}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Dúvida qual forma utilizar? Tem diferença de performance?

Exemplo no [JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dyb8ne27/](https://jsfiddle.net/dyb8ne27/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

claudsan seu primeiro controller funciona pois ele esta sendo declarado dentro do global scope (window).

Se você isolar o scope usando IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)
o seu var controller1 não vai ser válido e seu código vai quebrar pois não encontrará a variável.

exemplo:

```
//Declaração da aplicacao
$myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//Declaração dos controllers
var controller1 = function ($scope,$http){
 $scope.name = 'controller declaracao 1';
}

$myApp.controller('controller2',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.name = 'controller declaracao 2';
}]);
```

Erro:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'controller1' is not a function, got undefined
```

Usando IIFE você precisa declarar o controller1 igual você declarou o controller2, e o Angular vai fazer conseguir acessar o controler1:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  //Declaração da aplicacao
  $myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  //Declaração dos controllers
  var controller1 = function ($scope,$http){
   $scope.name = 'controller declaracao 1';
  };

  $myApp.controller('controller1', ['$scope', '$http', controller1]);

  $myApp.controller('controller2',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.name = 'controller declaracao 2';
  }]);

}());
```

Espero que eu tenha ajudado e lembre-se que sempre é uma boa prática não sujar o global scope (window).

Caso queira saber mais sobre o IIFE veja esse [link](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: consegui entender o funcionamento apos algum tempo, mas de toda forma muito obrigado pela explicação mais detalhada que possivelmente vai ajudar mais gente.

Answer (score 1):

No que se refere a performance não existe diferença nenhuma.
Mas existe algumas diferença que vou listar abaixo:

**O que acontece quando voce usa a diretiva(directive) ng-controller:**

- Um novo scope ($scope) e criado para cada DOM elemento que utilizar a diretiva. Ou seja voce pode ter uma mesma *view* (template) com varios elementos utilizando o mesmo controller.
- A relacao entre elemento e o controller eh bem explicita, ja que voce sabe que esse controller esta sendo definido para um especifico elemento do DOM
- Quando voce usar o inspect (console), vai ficar bem mais facil de ver aonde exatamente o controller esta sendo usado ja que o nome ng-controller vai estar visivel no HTML.

**O que acontece quando voce definir o controller atraves de uma rota/url (route):**

- Um novo scope ($scope) e criado para cada rota/url (route). Ou seja, ele vai estar disponivel para toda a *view* (template) que fizer parte daquela rota.
- Atraves do propriedade `resolve: {}` do rota/url (route) voce pode injetar dependencias no controller
- Nao existe relacao direta entre o controller e a view. A relacao existe entre o controller e a rota/url (route).

Nao existe uma forma certa ou errada sobre como declarar Controllers em AngularJS. As duas formas acimas sao corretas e funcionam. Tudo vai realmente depender do requisitos do seu projeto - e as vezes ate preferencia pessoal.

Um exemplo de cenario para usar o controller atraves de uma rota/url (route), eh quando voce precisa utilizar o mesmo template(view) para duas url/rotas diferentes mas a logica e os dados para cada url/rota deve ser diferente.

Como voce precisa usar o mesmo template(view), voce nao pode utilizar o ng-controller na view, porque esse tem que mudar dependendo da rota.
Entao a solucao eh definir diferente controllers para cada rota e ainda utilizar um unico template.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Estou entendendo que sua pergunta é referente à diferença entre a versão sem declaração de injeções de dependências...

```
var controller1 = function ($scope,$http){}
```

e a versão com adição à coleção de *injectables* via método `controller` e com declaração de dependências:

```
$myApp.controller('controller2',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {}]);
```

Se este é o caso, vamos por partes:

### Sem declaração de injeções de dependências

O seu código está fazendo o seguinte:

```
var             // Declaração de variável no escopo atual
controller1 =   // Nome do controller
function (      // A interface da função definirá as dependências
$scope,         // Injeta a dependência para o módulo $scope 
                //     usando o handler default
$http           // Injeta a dependência para o módulo $http
                //     usando o handler default
){
...             // Corpo da função
}
```

Este formato mantém o código enxuto e terso. Dependências são resolvidas usando seus *handlers* padrão, o que é conveniente caso você esteja utilizando um serviço padrão repetidamente.

Como o Angular não faz idéia do que `controller1` significa, ele irá mapear o DOM até encontrar um objeto com o mesmo nome, certificar-se de que o objeto é uma função, e que esta função pode ser mapeada como um *controller*. Isso toma tempo - não muito, porém é um *overhead*.

### Com declaração de dependências

```
$myApp          // Referência ao objeto que contém a aplicação
.controller(    // Declaração de controle 
'controller2',  // Nome do controller
[               // coleção de objetos; N referências a dependências,
                //     Último parâmetro será a função que as consome.
'$scope',       // Mapeando a dependência $scope para a posição 0
'$http',        // Mapeando a dependência $http para a posição 1
function(       // Interface da função
$scope,         // apelido (handler) da dependência na posição 0
$http           // apelido (handler) da dependência na posição 1
) {
...             // Corpo da função
}]);
```

Este método é mais complexo, porém oferece mais possibilidades. Imagine que você quer escrever um controller genérico que espera receber uma dependência que possui os métodos Get(id), GetAll(), Remove().

Ao invés de re-escrever o seu controller a cada vez que necessitar implementar um controlador para cada nova implementação desta dependência, você só necessitará trocar a referência mapeada. Exemplo:

Original

```
$myApp.controller('dep1Controller',[ '$scope', 'dep1svc', function($scope, dependencia) {}]);
```

Nova versão

```
$myApp.controller('dep2Controller',[ '$scope', 'dep2svc', function($scope, dependencia) {}]);
```

As funções internas dos controllers irão referenciar `dependencia`, completamente ignorantes se os métodos chamados são pertencentes a `dep1svc` ou `dep2svc` - permitindo assim uma maior abstração do seu código.